# how to split mesh - by its joining edges

Tags: mesh, edges

so, usually I'd just grab the desired faces and 'separate>selection', thus making a new separate mesh in the collection list.

but this is going to be a nightmare because of all the faces etc.
BUT I do have a nice clean line to cut along. its easy to select this line of edges, but now how to use that to split the mesh into two discrete meshes?

cos so far i've only managed to separate that specific line..

Dear mods.
Can you show me how to answer the question if there is no 'answer question UI' to use?
I'm trying to give credit where its due, and show subsequent viewers where to find the solution, but instead you just delete my answers.

Presumably its the 'Tick' symbol, which doesn't appear next to Moonboots or Robin's comments. so how do you imagine I can correctly use the site if you don't provide the tools to do so?
I'm trying to give credit where its due, and show subsequent viewers where to find the solution, but instead you just delete my answers. which, DO show the answer.
[image]

Comment: You can use V to rip, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: ... followed by right-click to drop in place, and L with the mouse hovering over the contiguous island of faces you want, to select it.